# Quarkus - Is there a way to empty the log file at every initiation instead of appending to it?

Tags: java, quarkus

I want the log file to be empty every time I start the application. But I cannot find a way to do so. There is nothing stated as such in the Quarkus documentation (https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#quarkus-log-logging-log-config_quarkus.log.file-file-logging).

I would really appreciate if someone can tell me how to do it or suggest a workaround in case it is not possible.

*This is the logging configurations in the application properties file*

```
# Log
quarkus.log.category."com.helesto".level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.level=INFO

# Log File
quarkus.log.file.enable = true
quarkus.log.file.format = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c{3.}] (%t) %s%e%n
quarkus.log.file.path = logs/test.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I configured quarkus to begin a new file on reboot.

As documented [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-core_quarkus.log.file.rotation.rotate-on-boot:%7E:text=quarkus.log.file.rotation.rotate,suffix%20for%20it%20to%20work.) you need to either set a max-file-size or configure a file-suffix for it to work.

This is my working configuration:

```
quarkus.log.file.enable= true
quarkus.log.file.path= /log/backend.log
quarkus.log.file.level= DEBUG
quarkus.log.file.format= %d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
quarkus.log.file.rotation.file-suffix= .yyyy-MM-dd
quarkus.log.file.rotation.rotate-on-boot= true
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-backup-index= 31
```

with this configuration it produces a daily log and begin a new file on reboot up to maximum 31 files.